# Is the root/rhizomes of ground elder edible?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables, root

Ground elder is a terrible weed with delicious leaves. But is the root edible too?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegopodium_podagraria):

> Aegopodium podagraria, commonly called ground elder, herb gerard, bishop's weed, goutweed, and snow-in-the-mountain, is a perennial plant in the carrot family (Apiaceae) that grows in shady places.
>
> [...]
>
> The tender leaves have been used in antiquity and throughout the Middle Ages as a spring leaf vegetable, much as spinach was used.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on http://www.dgsgardening.btinternet.co.uk/freefood.htm

Ground-elder
Aegopodium podagraria   all parts edible
young leaves in salads or cooked as a spinach,
roots dried and ground into a flour.

Jeannet